# I'm not sure if my subscripts are lining up correctly in this elementary number theoretic induction proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

First, the motivation for the below lemma is to use in a proof that every number has a unique representation in a base. My question is that when using the inductive hypothesis, I'm not sure if my subscripts match up perfectly as stated in the inductive hypothesis, perhaps rendering this proof invalid. Would I need to alter anything for this to be correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's clearer via polynomials. Suppose $\,f,\,g\,$ are polynomials with integer coefficients $\in [0,n\!-\!1].\,$ We show $\,f(n) = g(n)\,\Rightarrow\,f = g,\,$ i.e. they have equal coefficients, using induction on their max degree $\,d.\,$   If $\,d = -1\,$ then $\,f=0=g.\,$  Else $\,d\ge 0.\,$  $\,f(n) = g(n)\Rightarrow f(0)\equiv g(0)\pmod n\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{f(0)=g(0)}\,$  since both are $\in [0,n\!-\!1].\,$ So $\,f'(x) = (f(x)\!-\!\color{#c00}{f(0)})/x,\,$ $\,g'(x) = (g(x)\!-\!\color{#c00}{g(0)})/x\,$   have smaller max degree, $\rm\color{#c00}{and}$ $\,f'(n) = g'(n)\,$ so, by induction, $\,f' = g',\,$ thus $\, f = g.$

Comment: Thank you Bill. I understand that your method is simpler. But is my method still correct, or is there an issue that needs fixing?

Comment: Both proofs are essentially the same: show that the head (constant) terms are congruent mod $\,n\,$ hence equal, then use induction on their tails, after cancelling $n$ (or $x$). I highly recommend that you compare the two proofs, then restructure yours using polynomials, since it is much more readable that way. All the obfuscatory subscripts make it difficult to discern the essence of the matter. Using polynomial notation eliminates all of those inessential details.

Comment: Thank you Bill! Your posts are always very helpful. Cheers.